# Assigning more than one video file to an id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, carrierwave

Am working on a video application where the app in rails receive video files from different user. The videos are sent individually not multiple upload. Am trying to make a user to me able to store more than one video in the same row. for example. if a user has uploaded a video before( say video1), if the same user( with same id) upload another video, i want to update the existing video field( video1, video2 or something similar). I don't want to create another row for the same user. In summary i want to link a user to more than one video submission without adding a new row. Am currently using `carrierwave gem`, how can i achieve this

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :videos, VideoUploader
end
```

video field above

```
submit = Submission.find(8) #asumming 8 is the id of the same user
submit.videos = params[:videos] #new parameter coming in
```

was also thinking of concantenating both the old valid and new valid seperated by a comma, but don't know how to handle that when calling the field.

Answer (score 1):

You need another model , lets call it Video that will have VideoUploader mounted, than you can have one-to-many relationship

Comment: yes, was thinking there is another way, didn't want to create another model initially.  i guess i have to now.

Comment: yeah, its a standard way to do it